# I am getting errors trying to use pip and I cannot understand the error message. Can someone please tell me what to do?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, command-prompt

I am trying to use the command "pip install beautifulsoup"
I have also tried to use "python -m pip install kivy==1.11.1"

Here is the error im getting while trying to install beautifulsoup :

[image: command prompt error]

please help me with this error , is the error in pip ?

Comment: Please Ankit read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `pip install beautifulsoup4` instead of `pip install beautifulsoup`

Answer (score 1):

You nead to do : `pip install beautifulsoup4`
The beautifulsoup 1 is too old...

Answer (score 1):

read your error messages before asking us please.

[image: look at your screenshots]

Answer (score 1):

Try: `python -m pip install beautifulsoup` or `python -m pip install beautifulsoup4`